# Function to find Optimal value to divide a dataframe in two groups considering a criteria based on mean and standard deviation

Tags: r

I am trying to divide a dataframe in two groups. The data frame has a structure like this:

```
X=data.frame(x1=c(1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,9,9,
    11,2,4,45,67,89,1,1,
    5,5,5,6,6,6,9,9,9,11,
    11,8,8,8,51,90,40,15,
    30,11,8,9,9,1,5,5,100,
    67,78,98,34,25,51,45))
```

For this I want to compute an optimal value that is in an given interval.  This value will divide the dataframe in two groups. First group G1 all values of x1 that are greater than optimal value and second group G2 all values of x1 that are less than or equal optimal value. The criteria I am considering is the next:

```
mean.G1+mean.G2<=mean(Data$X)
```

and

```
sd.G1+sd.G2<=sd(Data$X)
```

I want to extract the optimal in the iterations in the given interval. For example the interval is from 10 to 100 then I select a value `10` then the function I am looking for must make it

```
G1=data.frame(X[X$x1>10,]
G2=data.frame(X[X$x1<=10,]
```

After of this I compute mean and sd of G1 and G2:

```
mean(G1$X.X.x1...10...)=48.45; sd(G1$X.X.x1...10...)=30.76306
mean(G2$X.X.x1....10...)=5.34375; sd(G2$X.X.x1....10...)=2.902828
```

After I compute mean and sd for variable `x1` in `X`:

```
mean(X$x1)=21.92308; sd(X$x1)=28.3921
```

Then I proceed to compare mean and sd of `x1` with `mean(G1)+mean(G2)` and `sd(G1)+sd(G2)`. Then like `mean(G1)+mean(G2)` and `sd(G1)+sd(G2)` are not less than or equal to mean(X$x1) and sd(X$x1), the function must prove with next values in interval like 11,12,etc. And in case that there is not optimal show any message. I was trying with for and while but I don't get the optimal. Thanks and i wait this is clear.

Comment: I think you are the same user in the question linked by @mnel comment. It is better for you to merge the 2 users to get more reputation and by consequence to get better answers.

Comment: I am looking for an optimal value that verify that constraints not different breap points

Answer (score 0):

Let G be the entire group and G1 and G2 be the subgroups and |G| let be the number of elements of G.

```
mean(G) = sum(G)/|G| 
        = sum(G1)/|G| + sum(G2)/|G|
        = sum(G1)/|G1| * |G1|/|G| + sum(G2)/|G2| * |G2| / |G|
        = mean(G1) * |G1|/|G| + mean(G2) * |G2| / |G|
        < mean(G1) + mean(G2)
```

where the last line is due to the fact that (1) all elements of G are positive so that mean(G1) and mean(G2) are necessarily positive and (2) there are fewer elements in G1 than G and similarly there are fewer elements in G2 than G so |G1|/|G| < 1 and |G2|/|G| < 1.  Thus your mean criterion will never be satisfied.

Comment: It might be quicker just to observe that the mean of G1 is bigger than the mean of G (since it lacks the lower values), so if all values are positive ...

Comment: hehe good point. But actually his criterion will always be trivially satisfied, as he says the sum of means "are not less than or equal to mean(X$x1)"...

Comment: Each subgroup must have at least 1 element for the means to be defined (and at least 2 for the sd's to be defined) so no subgroup may be empty.  Furthermore it would not make sense from the perspective of what is trying to be achieved anyways.